# Fluid TYPO3 Flux 500 error after Image Upload from Flexform

Tags: typo3, fluid, flux, server-error, fal

I use `TYPO3 7.6.2`with `Flux 7.3.0`, `fluidcontent 4.4.0` and `vhs 2.4.0` I've made a lot of FluidTYPO3 Content Elements before. At my current project, I'll use an image / FAL upload. If I try to upload an image, I've got an Server Error 500. I cannot upload an image.

I also try it with standard code from an example like [this](https://fluidtypo3.org/library/code-examples.html?tx_fluidshare_display%5Bgist%5D=5&tx_fluidshare_display%5Baction%5D=display&tx_fluidshare_display%5Bcontroller%5D=Gist&cHash=e403004449572e5ede2dd38d6d268f99). And here's my example, no chance to upload any image.

```
<flux:form id="carousel" options="{useTypoScript: 0, Fluidcontent: {sorting: 101}, group: 'FCE', icon: '{f:uri.resource(path: \'Icons/Content/Carousel.png\')}'}">

            <flux:form.sheet name="imgGallerySheetImages">
                <flux:field.inline.fal name="settings.imgGalleryFalImageItems" multiple="true"
                                       maxItems="45"
                                       collapseAll="true" />
            </flux:form.sheet>


        </flux:form>
...
```

I'm using this snippet at the same server, another TYPO3 (6.2) and another subdomain. It's the same server. But I've no problems in the past with it.

I also can upload 'normal' images via `text&media`-Content Element, but not with my `flux-flexform`

[image: 500 error image upload flexform typo3]

Comment: Use the inspection tool of your browser to check the response for this request, it's quite possible you have error stack there. Also check sys_log table and Apache error log. Rise the log level if required in the Install Tool

Comment: Oha, some errors .. `/typo3/index.php?ajaxID=%2Fajax%2Frecord%2Finline%2Fcreate&ajaxToken=5b80c2d3499389fa6c0718c706086659478cb871 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` at my browser inspect tool ...

Comment: ... and at sys_log: `Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1446996319: Configuration retrieved from FlexForm is incomplete or not of type "inline". | UnexpectedValueException thrown in file /homepages/.../Controller/FormInlineAjaxController.php in line 855. Requested URL: http://domain.de/typo3/index.php?ajaxID=%%2Fajax%%2Frecord%%2Finline%%2Fcreate&ajaxToken=5b80c2d3499389fa6c0718c706086659478cb871`

Comment: I also found github flux issue, that's my problem: [https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/1013]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue to my problem at FluidTYPO3/Flux: https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux/issues/1013

Here's the TYPO3 Core fix: http://p.cweiske.de/270
`typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Controller/FormInlineAjaxController.php` and
Fluidcontnet fix: https://github.com/monosize/fluidcontent/blob/3556fe61f996fc0eec7e02e91b9c3a50071073b3/Classes/Provider/ContentProvider.php
`fluidcontent/Classes/Provider/ContentProvider.php`

It worked fine and I hope the problem will be solved with TYPO3 7.6.3
[image: FAL upload typo3 fluidcontent/flux]

Answer (score 0):

With flux 7.4.0 no patches are necessary anymore. flux contains a workaround now, see https://github.com/NamelessCoder/flux/commit/6508a5fb26af1511ab5d6309d7e6ffffcc222f1d

Comment: you're right ... today I reinstall fluidcontent+flux with the latest versions with no hacks and it works.